# Inverse Fourier transform rectangle function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I got some questions concerning the inverse Fouriertransform of $\hat{f}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathbf{1}_{[-\pi,\pi]}$.

One knows that $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$. But as a result 
$$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x},& x\neq 0,\\
1,& x=0. 
\end{cases}$$
is not an element of $L^1(ℝ)$. So I have to take the inverse Fourier transform defined on $L^2(ℝ)$, which is given by
$$f(x)=\lim\limits_{\lambda \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} \hat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi x}\,d\xi.\quad (\star)$$ 
Am I right? Does $(\star)$ hold for almost all $x\in ℝ$ or for all $x\in \mathbb{R}?$

Is then the following true?
For all $\lambda > \pi$ we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} \hat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\xi}\,d\xi=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ix\xi}\,d\xi=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}.$$
Then for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\{0\}$ we get
$$f(x)=\lim\limits_{\lambda \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} \hat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\xi}\,d\xi=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}.$$
With $f(0)=1$ we get for almost all $x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x)=\operatorname{sinc}(x):=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x},& x\neq 0,\\
1,& x=0. 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Parseval theorem is that if $G \in L^2$ and $g_\lambda(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} G(\xi)e^{i\xi x}\,d\xi$ then $\lim\limits_{\lambda \to \infty} g_\lambda$ is a sequence of continuous functions which converges in $L^2$, here it is obvious because $g_\lambda$ is constant for $\lambda \ge \pi$. The pointwise convergence almost everywhere of $\lim\limits_{\lambda \to \infty} g_\lambda(x)$ is another more complicated story. Also you should make clear the difference between inverse Fourier transform and Fourier inversion theorem.

Comment: Is now $f(x)=sinc(x)$ for all $x\in ℝ$ or for almost all $x \in ℝ$? - @reuns

Comment: The Fourier inversion theorem says $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathbf{1}_{[-\pi,\pi]}$ is the Fourier transform of $sinc(x)$, Fourier transform $L^2 \to L^2$ so equality in $L^2$ sense. If two continuous functions are equal in $L^2$ they are equal pointwise.